# Signing message in .NET Standard 2.0 with HMACSHA

Tags: c#, .net-core-2.0, .net-standard-2.0

I have old code and would like to use it in .NET Standard 2.0. I have found System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1 and I know how to compute hash but I don't know how to do the signing. How to write code below using .NET Standard 2?

```
public string GenerateSignature(string key, string content)
        {
            var keyMaterial = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(key, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
            var macAlgorithm = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("HMAC_SHA1");
            var macKey = macAlgorithm.CreateKey(keyMaterial);

            var buffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(content, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

            var signatureBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Sign(macKey, buffer);
            var signature = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(signatureBuffer);

            return signature;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of the HMAC stuff is unchanged between net standard and older framework versions. The following code should work in .NET 4.5.1, Net Standard 1.3 and above and .NET Core. It is slightly adapted from working code to match your method

```
public string GenerateSignature(string key, string content)
{
    var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1();
    hmac.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    var contentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
    var signature = hmac.ComputeHash(contentBytes);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
}
```